# Why does Explorer crash when context-clicking this filename?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, context-menu

In my [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) configuration directory, I have a file named `Home%20server%20(remote)`.

When I tried to context-click it in Explorer, I got the "Windows Explorer has stopped working" message with the following problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX64
  Application Name: explorer.exe
  Application Version:  6.1.7601.17567
  Application Timestamp:    4d672ee4
  Fault Module Name:    IsoWindowMenu64.dll
  Fault Module Version: 1.0.0.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e926333
  Exception Offset: 0000000000009774
  Exception Code:   c0000417
  Exception Data:   0000000000000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: e410
  Additional Information 2: e41038cd7ca591fe8db0f5704ee397b0
  Additional Information 3: dcb5
  Additional Information 4: dcb5e0e8fc94138b472718af02532221
```

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

What about this filename is causing Explorer to crash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Fault Module Name: **IsoWindowMenu64.dll**

this DLL crashes the Explorer. From waht I figured out on google this DLL belongs to this tool:

**BDlot DVD Clone**

http://www.bdlot.com/

Update or remove this tool.

Answer (score -1):

Check the amount of entries in your context menu. Mine was overloaded. I used CCleaner to disable ones I don't use and problem went away.